# How can I split up a massive feature module into multiple smaller modules?

Tags: features

I have one massive unmaintainable features module that I want to split up into smaller, manageable features. Can I disable the massive module without it removing or disabling content types and dependencies, as well as strongarm variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across [this solution](https://www.drupal.org/node/663136#comment-6997536) which suggests using CTools Bulk Exporter to get the features back into the database so they can be re-exported as smaller features.

> Think I've found an alternative solution to get your exported objects
>   back into the database so you can safely disable/remove your features.
>
> 1) Export everything you want in the database using CTools Bulk
>   Exporter (admin/structure/bulk-export). Put the module it generates
>   into your modules folder (eg. my_exports_module) 2) Disable the
>   features containing the objects you just exported 3) Enable the module
>   CTools Bulk Exporter created for you 4) Download Drush CTools Export
>   Bonus & enable it 5) Run the following drush command: drush cbsa
>   my_exports_module 6) Disable my_exports_module
>
> Tested this with view modes/fields/... created in Display Suite -
>   everything went better than expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create new features while your original feature is enabled.

Create a new feature and under "Advanced options" tick "Allow conflicts to be added". Now all your components, even those added to other features before will be available.

[image: Add feature components even though they are added to other features]